# How can I get legal style indentation on section, subsection, subsubsec.. using titlesec?

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec

So far, I've been trying code from various examples, and landed with:

```
\usepackage(titlesec)
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\hspace{2em}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\hspace{3em}}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

to indent the headers and their numbering. But I don't know how to get the content within each section/subsection/subsubsection to have an indented margin. In other words, I'd like to have the section/subsection/subsubsection content to be in line with it's indented header.

Is titlesec able to do this? I've been battling with the documentation, but I think they assume some more tex knowledge than I have as everything I try doesn't seem to work.

I'd like to use titlesec because, according to my understanding, I won't have to make any further adjustments while writing the document. I'm using pandoc to generate that part from markdown, so I can't have inline formatting on my sections.

Added the following as per comment requests:

Here is what I have:

[image: What I have]

And, here is what I would like:

[image: What I would like]

Or, I would like something like this:

[image: I would like this also]

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) not everyone knows what 'legal style indentation' looks like, and even 'to be in line with it's indented header' is not helpful (to me) --- is there no image you could point us to? (2) it is always better to provide a complete but minimal example that starts with `\documentclass{<whatever>}` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: rather than indenting the body, change the margins of the document globally using `geometry` and alter the indent of the *headings*- this will be much easier

Comment: Do you want to automate this? Of course, it is possible *without* automation...

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions, I would be ecstatic if I can automate this, but I may end up settling with @cmhughes idea of global margins. Otherwise, I'm open to more suggestions. I'm using `documentclass{article}` for no particular reason.

Answer (score 8):

This is surely possible, without automation, using the [`changepage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)'s `adjustwidth` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage,lipsum,titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{changepage,lipsum,titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {2em}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection} {3em}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{0pt}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{adjustwidth}{3em}{0pt}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

The first argument to `adjustwidth` is the left-hand indentation, while the second is the right-hand indentation.

The above MWE also includes Gonzalo's suggestions for better alignment and true-to-`titlesec` spacing of sectional units using `\titlespacing`.

Answer (score 4):

As a comparison, ConTeXt provides a `\startsection...\stopsection` version of the section heading commands, and keys `beforesection` and `aftersection` to hook into the start and stop of the section. So, one can simply set `beforesection=\startnarrower` and `aftersection=\stopnarrower` to get the desired effect.

In the code below, I define a new `narrower` environment to avoid interference.

```
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\definenarrower
  [sectionnarrower]
  [left=2em,
   default=left]

\setuphead
  [subsection]
  [
    margin=2em,
    beforesection={\startsectionnarrower},
    aftersection={\stopsectionnarrower},
  ]

\setuphead
  [subsubsection]
  [
    margin=4em,
    beforesection={\startsectionnarrower},
    aftersection={\stopsectionnarrower},
  ]
```

With this setup, you don't need to add any commands in the main document.

```
\starttext

\startsection
    [title={A section}]

  \input ward

  \startsubsection
      [title={A subsection}]

    \input ward

    \startsubsubsection
        [title={A subsubsection}]

      \input ward

    \stopsubsubsection

    \input ward

  \stopsubsection

  \input ward
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]

To get section numbers in the margin, add

```
\setuphead[alternative=inmargin]
```