# Indentation of sections and paragraphs to show hierarchy

Tags: spacing, indentation, margins, paragraphs

I am having troubles with the format of a work that I'm doing. The default output of LaTeX looks like:

```
1.1.     Section A
   Latex latex latex latex.
1.1.1.   Subsection A-1
   Latex latex latex latex.
```

But the format I want is:

```
1.1. Section A
     Latex latex latex latex.
     1.1.1. Subsection A-1
            Latex latex latex latex.
```

The numbers of the subsections should start in the same vertical line to the text of the section, and also I would like to decrease the spacing between the number and the text, the indentation of the paragraph too.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Berthin. Regarding the last part of your question: you can change the paragraph indentation using `\parindent=0pt`. If you want to have extra space between paragraphs (to make up for the lack of indentation), you can use the `parskip` package.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt help me :(. I want to do something like this \titlelabel{\thetitle.\ } \parindent=40pt for section, and for subsection i wish that subsection starts at 40pt (--40pt--"1.1.1. Subsection") and the paragraphs which follows the subsection start at 80pt

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109328/323

Answer (score 7):

In the absence of a better answer, here is my attempt.

[image]

Some comments on my approach.

- I used the examples on **[Vincent Zoonekynd's webpage](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html)** as a starting point.
- I set the ((sub)sub)section number in a box of a specific width, and then the ((sub)sub)section title to the right of it. Normally, there's just a `\quad` of horizontal space between the two, but that would cause alignment problems once the section number goes into double figures.
- I adjust `\leftskip` to get the indentations at the required levels.
- The indentation for `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` is currently `10mm`, `12mm` and `14mm`, respectively. These numbers are set at the top of my code (see below). I chose an increasing sequence of values to account for the fact that subsubsections have longer numbers (e.g. 1.1.1).

I see two main problems with my approach.

- The `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` are redefined from scratch. There must be a simpler way of doing this, right? Maybe the `titlesec` package would help.
- The spacing above and below each ((sub)sub)section heading is fixed, and is roughly similar to the `article` class. This means that if you load a different class like `book`, you won't get the intended spacings. On the bright side, it's perfectly easy to adjust the spacings manually, to your liking.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration
\def\sectionindent{10mm}
\def\subsectionindent{12mm}
\def\subsubsectionindent{14mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Some derived quantities
% (you should manually update these)

\def\subsectiontotalindent{22mm} 
% = \sectionindent + \subsectionindent

\def\subsubsectiontotalindent{36mm}
% = \sectionindent + \subsectionindent + \subsubsectionindent

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The following code is adapted from some sample code by 
% Vincent Zoonekynd, made available at the following website:
% http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Redefining \section and \section*

\def\section{\@ifstar\unnumberedsection\numberedsection}
\def\numberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \numberedsectionwithtwoarguments\numberedsectionwithoneargument}
\def\unnumberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument}
\def\numberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode\Large\bfseries\raggedright
  \rlap{\thesection}%
  \hspace{\sectionindent}%
  #2
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thesection}%
    #1}%
  \leftskip=\sectionindent\relax%
  }
\def\unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
%  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode\Large\bfseries\raggedright
  %\rlap{\thesection}%
  \hspace{\sectionindent}%
  #2
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
%    \protect\numberline{\thesection}%
    #1}%
  \leftskip=\sectionindent\relax%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Redefining \subsection and \subsection*
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\subsection{\@ifstar\unnumberedsubsection\numberedsubsection}
\def\numberedsubsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \numberedsubsectionwithtwoarguments\numberedsubsectionwithoneargument}
\def\unnumberedsubsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \unnumberedsubsectionwithtwoarguments\unnumberedsubsectionwithoneargument}
\def\numberedsubsectionwithoneargument#1{\numberedsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\unnumberedsubsectionwithoneargument#1{\unnumberedsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\numberedsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode\large\bfseries\raggedright
  \hspace{\sectionindent}%
  \rlap{\thesubsection}%
  \hspace{\subsectionindent}%
  #2
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thesubsection}%
    #1}%
  \leftskip=\subsectiontotalindent\relax%
  }
\def\unnumberedsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
%  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode\large\bfseries\raggedright
  \hspace{\sectionindent}%
  %\rlap{\thesubsection}%
  \hspace{\subsectionindent}%
  #2
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
%    \protect\numberline{\thesubsection}%
    #1}%
  \leftskip=\subsectiontotalindent\relax%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Redefining \subsubsection and \subsubsection*
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\subsubsection{\@ifstar\unnumberedsubsubsection\numberedsubsubsection}
\def\numberedsubsubsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \numberedsubsubsectionwithtwoarguments\numberedsubsubsectionwithoneargument}
\def\unnumberedsubsubsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \unnumberedsubsubsectionwithtwoarguments\unnumberedsubsubsectionwithoneargument}
\def\numberedsubsubsectionwithoneargument#1{\numberedsubsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\unnumberedsubsubsectionwithoneargument#1{\unnumberedsubsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\numberedsubsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
  \refstepcounter{subsubsection}%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright
  \hspace{\subsectiontotalindent}%
  \rlap{\thesubsubsection}%
  \hspace{\subsubsectionindent}%
  #2
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thesubsubsection}%
    #1}%
  \leftskip=\subsubsectiontotalindent\relax%
  }
\def\unnumberedsubsubsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
%  \refstepcounter{subsubsection}%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright
  \hspace{\subsectiontotalindent}%
  %\rlap{\thesubsubsection}%
  \hspace{\subsubsectionindent}%
  #2
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{%
%    \protect\numberline{\thesubsubsection}%
    #1}%
  \leftskip=\subsubsectiontotalindent\relax%
}


\makeatother

\parindent=0pt

\newcommand\randomtext{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac lorem ac justo auctor elementum. Ut mattis mauris et orci mollis sollicitudin.\par}

\begin{document}
\randomtext
\section{Introduction}
\randomtext
\randomtext
\subsection{Subsection}
\randomtext
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\randomtext
\subsubsection*{Subsubsection without a number}
\randomtext
\subsubsection{Subsubsection with a number}
\randomtext
\subsection{Another subsection}
\randomtext
\subsubsection{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\section{Hello}
\randomtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice attempt; but lists will not be indented properly when in subsections.

Comment: Hm. Is that easily fixed?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. But unfortunately, it fails in equal indentation both in section/subsection/subsubsection titles including proper alignment of leftskip like section/sub/subsubsectiontotal