# Left margin set different for every /section /subsection

Tags: sectioning, margins, leftmargin

I need to set certain margins for every chapter, section... so each block appears to be 'in his own level'. Not only for the titles but for the whole text in each section. I need it to be automatically done and not having to set horizontal margin each time I add a new section/subsection.  I'm already using titlesec in the main document.

Here is my example code.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel} % espanol
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % acentos sin codigo
    
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
añslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfj
\section{Section}
añslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfj
añslkdfañlksdfjalsdjflasdjflaksjdflkasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
añslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfj

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
añslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfjañslkdfjalsdkfjasdkfj


\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of how I need it to look like.
Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: There is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117724/ but that is probably not very robust.