# Komascript - resetting geometry inside the document

Tags: header-footer, indentation, koma-script

In [Indenting text after numbered paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219067/) I was given excellent advice on how to indent numbered paragraphs in Komascript,

```
\newcommand\secnumindent{1.5cm}
 .. command for the section itself
\hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset + \secnumindent\relax    
\textwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth-\secnumindent\relax    
\paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth -\secnumindent\relax
```

and how to compensate and adjust the footer with

```
\usepackage[
  headwidth=\the\textwidth+\secnumindent:-\secnumindent,
  footwidth=head:-\secnumindent,
  headsepline,% to show the headwidth
  footsepline% to show the footwidth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

Five months on I now wish to be able to reset the geometry in the body of the text for some long tables in the appendix. For these tables I am currently proposing to rotate them to landscape with

```
\begin{landscape}
```

The indentation for the section numbers, and the corresponding adjustments to the footer no longer make sense in this local environment. Am unclear on how to unset the above commands in the body of the document. If I just reset the \hoffset, \textwidth and \paperwidth variables - then footer shifts. But then I can't see how to reset the footer parameters.

Note - I also have tried alternative options such as

```
\KOMAoptions{pagesize,paper=landscape,DIV=12}
```

to rotate the text for the appendix. This gives the footer in a different axis to the \landscape solution. This still leads to the issue that you need to then adjust the footer to get the elements spread out across the full landscape width.

Comment: After changing KOMAoptions after `\begin{document}`you need to add `\recalctypearea`, otherwise nothing will happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\clearpage
\addtolength\hoffset{-\secnumindent}
\addtolength\textwidth{\secnumindent}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=text,footwidth=head}
```

[image]

---

Code for **KOMA-Script version 3.17 or newer**:

```
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
\documentclass[english, parskip=full, fontsize=11, DIV12, toc=left, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% just so we can see what is going on for now
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% tighten up spacing of lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcommand\p{\paragraph{}}

\newcommand\secnumindent{1.5cm}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[indent=-\secnumindent]{section,subsection,paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=0pt,counterwithin=subsection]{paragraph}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\parbox{\secnumindent}{\thesection\autodot}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\parbox{\secnumindent}{\thesubsection\autodot}}
\renewcommand\subsubsectionformat{\parbox{\secnumindent}{\thesubsubsection\autodot}}
\renewcommand\paragraphformat{\parbox{\secnumindent}{\theparagraph\autodot}}

% from the answer of @Steven:
\addtolength\hoffset{\secnumindent}
\addtolength\textwidth{-\secnumindent}
%
% make sure paragraphs reset counting also at sections    
%
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{section}
\makeatother
% to reset headwidth and footwidth
\usepackage[
  headwidth=\the\textwidth+\secnumindent:-\secnumindent,
  footwidth=head:-\secnumindent,
  headsepline,% to show the headwidth
  footsepline% to show the footwidth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{lscape}
%
% AND NOW WE BEGIN
%
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection {Subsection}\label{sec:first}
\p \blindtext
% a reference
\p See \ref{sec:first}
% an example numbered paragraph with an embedded list
\p \blindtext
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
and some words at the end of this para

% an example numbered paragraph with a simple equation
\p The period is defined by a pair of days ($D_l$, $D_u$) where 
\begin{align*}
D_{l} & =  \text{the lower date}  \\
D_{u} & =  \text{the upper date}
\end{align*}
and things happen for all days $d$ where $D_l <= d< D_u$. 
\section{Next section}
\subsection{Next subsection}
\p \blindtext
\clearpage
\addtolength\hoffset{-\secnumindent}
\addtolength\textwidth{\secnumindent}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=text,footwidth=head}
\begin{landscape}
  \Blindtext[10]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The code above works with **version 3.15 or newer** if you insert

```
% make sure that it also works with KOMA 3.15 or 3.16
\renewcommand\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{\parbox{\secnumindent}{#3\autodot}}
\providecommand\sectionformat{}\providecommand\subsectionformat{}
\providecommand\subsubsectionformat{}\providecommand\paragraphformat{}
```

before the redefinition of `\sectionformat` etc.

---

Code for **KOMA-Script version 3.12 or newer**:

```
\documentclass[english, parskip=full, fontsize=11, DIV12, toc=left, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% just so we can see what is going on for now
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
% tighten up spacing of lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
\newcommand\p{\paragraph{}\hspace*{-1em}}

\newcommand\secnumindent{1.5cm}
\renewcommand\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\parbox{\secnumindent}{#3\autodot}}}
% to make sure that it works with version 3.17 or newer:
  \let\sectionformat\relax\let\subsectionformat\relax
  \let\subsubsectionformat\relax\let\paragraphformat\relax
%
% from the answer of @Steven:
\addtolength\hoffset{\secnumindent}
\addtolength\textwidth{-\secnumindent}
% to reset headwidth and footwidth
\usepackage[
  headwidth=\the\textwidth+\secnumindent:-\secnumindent,
  footwidth=head:-\secnumindent,
  headsepline,% to show the headwidth
  footsepline% to show the footwidth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%
% make sure paragraphs reset counting at section and subsections
%
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{section}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{lscape}
%
% AND NOW WE BEGIN
%
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection {Subsection}\label{sec:first}
\p \blindtext
% a reference
\p See \ref{sec:first}
% an example numbered paragraph with an embedded list
\p \blindtext
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
and some words at the end of this para

% an example numbered paragraph with a simple equation
\p The period is defined by a pair of days ($D_l$, $D_u$) where 
\begin{align*}
D_{l} & =  \text{the lower date}  \\
D_{u} & =  \text{the upper date}
\end{align*}
and things happen for all days $d$ where $D_l <= d< D_u$. 
\section{Next section}
\subsection{Next subsection}
\p \blindtext
% inserted
\clearpage
\addtolength\hoffset{-\secnumindent}
\addtolength\textwidth{\secnumindent}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=text,footwidth=head}
\begin{landscape}
  \Blindtext[10]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```