# Enumerations with repeating numbers only of the same list type

Tags: lists, context

Using ConTeXt I am trying to produce a nested enumeration like the one below:

```
1  Level 1
   1.1 Level 2
       1.1.1 Level 3
             a) Level 3 subitem
             b) Level 3 subitem
```

I have the following:

```
\defineitemgroup[legal]
\setuplegal[each][n,repeat,joinedup][stopper=]

\setuplegal[1][width=1em]
\setuplegal[2][width=2em]
\setuplegal[3][width=3em]

\starttext

\startlegal
  \item Level 1
  \startlegal
    \item Level 2
    \startlegal
      \item Level 3
      \startitemize[a,joinedup][stopper=)]
        \item Level 3 subitem
        \item Level 3 subitem
      \stopitemize
    \stoplegal
  \stoplegal
\stoplegal

\stoptext
```

However, this produces:

[image: List]

Is there any way to configure the legal itemisation so that enumerations of other types (e.g. alphabetic or Roman) are not affected? Not sure whether this is relevant, but enumerations of other types can appear at any level, not just the 3rd level as shown above.

Comment: By page 2 of the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) manual, `\usepackage{enumitem}\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}` will do what you want.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm using ConTeXt, not LaTeX.

Comment: Appears to be a bug. I sent a bug report to the [mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg83253.html)

Comment: @Aditya: Is there any way that I can use a custom conversion to mimic the 1.2.3 numbering style so that I can just use `\startitemize[legal]` in conjunction with `\startitemize[a]`, or will this not help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is a bug. I have filed a bug-report on the context mailing list. In the meanwhile, if you need the correct output, use `legal` as itemize at the fourth level as well:

```
\defineitemgroup[legal]
\setuplegal[each][n,repeat,joinedup][stopper=]

\setuplegal[1][width=1em]
\setuplegal[2][width=2em]
\setuplegal[3][width=3em]

\starttext

\startlegal
  \item Level 1
  \startlegal
    \item Level 2
    \startlegal[norepeat]
      \item Level 3
      \startlegal[a,joinedup][stopper=)]
        \item Level 3 subitem
        \item Level 3 subitem
      \stoplegal
    \stoplegal
  \stoplegal
\stoplegal

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help :) but the requirement of `[norepeat]` might be an issue - for example, if there's an alphabetic list that occurs at the 1st level, then the very first level will turn off repeating numbers and so all levels under it will not have the "legal" numbering system. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: As far as I understand, you need `[norepeat]` to turn off the repeat option in the child nodes. Another option will be just to use regular sections for the higher levels. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109333/323

Comment: So there is no way to have only the `legal` itemisation numbers repeated? If not, I will have to try something a bit hackier I guess.

Comment: I did something a bit dirty. I'm going to accept your answer but I'm going to post what I actually ended up using just in case it helps other people.

Answer (score 1):

Since I need to have only the legal numbers repeated (so that other itemisations are not prefixed with the legal numbers), I did something a bit dirty:

```
\def\legalconversion#1{
  \dorecurse{\numexpr\currentitemlevel-1}{%
    \rawcounter[itemgroup:\currentparentitemgroup][\recurselevel].}%
  #1%
}

\defineconversion[legal][\legalconversion]

\setupitemgroup[itemize][joinedup]
\setupitemgroup[itemize][stopper=,itemalign=flushright,distance=1em]

\starttext

\startitemize[legal]
  \item Level 1
  \startitemize[legal]
    \item Level 2
    \startitemize[legal]
      \item Level 3
      \startitemize[a][stopper=)]
        \item Level 3 subitem
        \item Level 3 subitem
      \stopitemize
    \stopitemize
  \stopitemize
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

This produces the following:

[image: result]

This works regardless of what level the other-type-itemisations are at, although, without further dirtiness, this only works if the top-level itemisation is `legal`, and only works as long as adjacent sublevels are `legal` as well (e.g. `\startitemize[legal]\startitemize[a]\startitemize[legal]` doesn't work).

Comment: This is a reasonable approach; But this will fail if you have a legal item as a sub-item of a regular item. I think that even the approach with `repeat` fails in that case.