# Legal-style indentation with text on the same line as the subsection title

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

A legal document requires the indentation format as in Question [How can I get legal style indentation on section, subsection, subsubsec.. using titlesec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109328/how-can-i-get-legal-style-indentation-on-section-subsection-subsubsec-using).
I'm using the answer to the related question [automatic legal-style indentation in all ((sub)sub)sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357851/automatic-legal-style-indentation-in-all-subsubsections?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The issue is with having text on the same line as the subsection number. If I  put `\subsection{Lorem ipsum bla bla ...}`, this breaks the page formatting. My other approach is to modify  the  @David Carlisle answer by changing `\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}` to `[runin]`. However, this produces an ident before the  subsection. Here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage,lipsum,titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{changepage,lipsum,titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {\leftmargin}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection} {\leftmargin}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\let\xsection\section
\def\section{\par
  \leftmargin0\p@
  \leftskip\leftmargin
  \@totalleftmargin\leftmargin\linewidth\textwidth
  \xsection}
\let\xsubsection\subsection
\def\subsection{\par
  \leftmargin20\p@
  \leftskip\leftmargin
  \@totalleftmargin\leftmargin\linewidth\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin\relax
  \xsubsection}
\let\xsubsubsection\subsubsection
\def\subsubsection{\par
  \leftmargin40\p@
  \leftskip\leftmargin
  \@totalleftmargin\leftmargin\linewidth\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin\relax
  \xsubsubsection}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
  \lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

And here's the result:
[image]
Question: How to get rid of the ident before the subsection?

Answer (score 3):

Setting

```
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0em}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

gives the correct result
[image]